Is there any method to solve build.gradle problem
I'm new to flutter and facing problem related to build.gradle and  couldn't figure out what's actually going wrong
Need detailed help!
1
2
3
4
I tried various command, search on YouTube  but didn't get any result

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please read Why should I not upload image of code/data/erroes

Please remove the "," from ext.kotlinversion "2.0.0".
It should be:
ext.kotlin_version = "2.0.0" 

